# jinja2 loop for flask ajax call to restart servers

Tags: python, ajax, flask, jinja2

I want to use ajax to restart servers from a flask web app.

**My solution**
Iterate over a folder of .bat files that restart servers, and send the name of the file to a flask function. 
In my html, I'm using jinja2 to loop over files, and then create links to the ajax call.

**Problem**
something is wrong with my ajax, because it doesn't do anything

*here is the view.*

```
@app.route('/restartajax/<computer>')
def restartajax(computer):
    print 'code'
    def runJob(computer):
        try:
            subprocess.call(r"\\covenas\decisionsupport\meinzer\production\bat\restart\%s" % computer)
        except Exception,e:
            print 'there was an exception', e
    thr = Thread(target = runJob, args = [computer])
    thr.start()
    return jsonify(result=computer)
```

html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{
  url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}">\x3C/script>')</script>

<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>

              <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="well well-lg">
            <div class="container">
        <h1>Restart a Computer or Server</h1>
        <p>Clickit.</p>
  {% for item in restartFiles %} 
  {% if 'Backup' not in item and 'dummy' not in item %}
  <div class="col-md-4">

<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/restartajax/'+item, {
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<h4>{{item}}</h4>
   <span id=result>?</span>
<p><a href=# id=calculate>restart {{item}}</a>
</div>
 {%endif%} {%endfor%}
```

**Modifications**

I modified based on the answer, and it works!

```
  {% for item in restartFiles %} 

  <div class="col-md-4">

<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a.calculate').bind('click', function() {
       var item = $(this).attr('id');

      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/restartajax/'+item, {
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<h4>{{item}}</h4>
   <span class="result">?</span>
<p><a href=# name = a class="calculate" id="{{ item }}">restart {{ item }}</a>
</div>
 {%endif%} {%endfor%}
```

the view

```
@app.route('/restartajax/<computer>')
def restartajax(computer):
    def runJob(computer):
        try:
            subprocess.call(r"\\covenas\decisionsupport\meinzer\production\bat\restart\%s" % computer)
        except Exception,e:
            print 'there was an exception', e
    thr = Thread(target = runJob, args = [computer])
    thr.start()
    return jsonify(result=computer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` doesn't seem to be defined inside your calculate function, and you haven't given it any way to work it out. You need to send something to the function that identifies which item you have clicked on.

Also, since you have multiple items, you need to choose a different ID for each link: it's invalid in HTML to have more than one ID with the same value. Use a class instead of an ID to bind the jQuery listener.

```
<a href="#" class="calculate" id="{{ item }}">restart {{item}}</a>

$('a.calculate').bind('click', function() {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    $.getJSON ...
```